# Drawer Menu implementation, how to close menu - IOS

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, ios7

I have an app, where i'm implementing a Drawer Menu, like Google+ but not can close the menu when did select in a row, I check this with debugger and when i send the message to CCKFNavDrawer the values of the propertys are zero or nil, how can solve this?

Repository [Here](https://bitbucket.org/Linuxito/drawermenu.git)

CCKFNavDrawer.m
I have a class with this method also have it in .h file

```
- (void)closeNavigationDrawer{

//    NSLog(@"close x=%f",self.menuView.center.x);
float duration = MENU_DURATION/self.menuWidth*abs(self.drawerView.center.x)+MENU_DURATION/2; // y=mx+c

// shawdow
[UIView animateWithDuration:duration
                      delay:0
                    options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut
                 animations:^{
                     self.shawdowView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.0 green:0.0 blue:0.0 alpha:0.0f];
                 }
                 completion:^(BOOL finished){
                     self.shawdowView.hidden = YES;
                 }];

// drawer
[UIView animateWithDuration:duration
                      delay:0
                    options:UIViewAnimationOptionBeginFromCurrentState
                 animations:^{
                     self.drawerView.frame = self.outFrame;
                 }
                 completion:nil];
self.isOpen= NO;
}
```

In the DrawerView.m have this method

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

   CCKFNavDrawer *c = [[CCKFNavDrawer alloc] init];
    [c closeNavigationDrawer];
}
```

Comment: Please post the section of code that you suspect is causing the problem or where you are seeing the issue.

Answer (score 0):

In your didSelectRowAtIndexPath you are allocating a new CCKFNavDrawer and calling the default initialiser but then you just call closeNavigatorDrawer straight away. Your drawer has never been added to a view.

Rather than creating a new drawer I think you must have a drawer you have created somewhere else in your program that you should be referencing in the row select method